# Azure release pipeline Regression test job failure due to error :- This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 86

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

## I Azure devops, i am getting error while running regression test job in release pipeline. The artifact is hosted in Azure repos. Full error stack is mentioned below. Please help on this scenario.

```
2022-11-17T07:32:37.8052533Z Tests in error: 
2022-11-17T07:32:37.8053113Z   getData(Academy.BrowserTest): session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 86(..)
2022-11-17T07:32:37.8054011Z 
2022-11-17T07:32:37.8054528Z Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
2022-11-17T07:32:37.8054792Z 
2022-11-17T07:32:37.8123963Z [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2022-11-17T07:32:37.8124674Z [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
2022-11-17T07:32:37.8125946Z [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2022-11-17T07:32:37.8148852Z [INFO] Total time:  01:11 min
2022-11-17T07:32:37.8150695Z [INFO] Finished at: 2022-11-17T07:32:37Z
2022-11-17T07:32:37.8151259Z [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2022-11-17T07:32:37.8166640Z [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project devops: There are test failures.
2022-11-17T07:32:37.8169627Z [ERROR] 
2022-11-17T07:32:37.8170486Z [ERROR] Please refer to D:\a\r1\a\_GBSAutomationTestRepo.git\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
2022-11-17T07:32:37.8171162Z [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
2022-11-17T07:32:37.8171546Z [ERROR] 
2022-11-17T07:32:37.8172050Z [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
2022-11-17T07:32:37.8172644Z [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
2022-11-17T07:32:37.8172947Z [ERROR] 
2022-11-17T07:32:37.8173332Z [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
2022-11-17T07:32:37.8174196Z [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
2022-11-17T07:32:37.8760477Z The process 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\maven\apache-maven-3.8.6\bin\mvn.cmd' failed with exit code 1
2022-11-17T07:32:37.8761396Z Could not retrieve code analysis results - Maven run failed.
2022-11-17T07:32:39.7735190Z Result Attachments will be stored in LogStore
2022-11-17T07:32:39.8293757Z Run Attachments will be stored in LogStore
2022-11-17T07:32:39.9011567Z ##[error]Build failed.
2022-11-17T07:32:39.9091599Z ##[section]Async Command Start: Publish test results
2022-11-17T07:32:40.2939741Z Publishing test results to test run '18'.
2022-11-17T07:32:40.2969758Z TestResults To Publish 2, Test run id:18
2022-11-17T07:32:40.3013991Z Test results publishing 2, remaining: 0. Test run id: 18
2022-11-17T07:32:41.6218305Z Published Test Run : https://dev.azure.com/gbsr2rindiarepos/AZGBSDemoProject01/_TestManagement/Runs?runId=18&_a=runCharts
2022-11-17T07:32:42.0349797Z Flaky failed test results are opted out of pass percentage
2022-11-17T07:32:42.0701567Z ##[section]Async Command End: Publish test results
2022-11-17T07:32:42.0703521Z ##[section]Finishing: Maven D:\a\r1\a/_GBSAutomationTestRepo.git/pom.xml
```

Perform regression testing via an implemented Release pipeline job in "de.azure.com" project

Comment: Hi @budhaditya, does the maven test run successfully in local? I find most similar issue that happens even in local. Have you check whether there are conflicting dependencies or update the old version 2.12.4 to the latest version here (mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/…) then refresh the POM for a try? If local run is successfully and only Azure devops pipeline task failed, could you kindly share the POM file and the release yaml definition for further investigation? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

download the latest chrome driver version and add them into the valid source directory. Build Agent will get it from there to launch the ChromeDriver from artifactory directory.